# Javascript Object Prototype

Tags: javascript

I was reading Prototypes in javascript and I have written 2 small js codes which are outputting exactly same. I just want to know what is the difference between them:

**Code 1:**

```
String.sam = function() { alert('fine') };
'ok'.sam();
```

**Code 2 with prototype:**

```
String.prototype.sam = function() { alert('fine') };
'ok'.sam();
```

Please clarify the difference and the better way to use the code.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Your first example doesn't work. What you are doing is creating a static method on the string object so you would have to call it statically

```
//OK
String.sam();
//not OK, raises error
'hello'.sam();
```

In your second example the keyword `this` will refer to the instance of the string you call it on. So you can do something like

```
String.prototype.sam = function() {
    console.log( this.toUpperCase() );
}

'hello'.sam(); // HELLO
```

This technique, although powerful is frowned upon in certain quarters. It is known as Guerrilla patching, Monkey punching or similar things.
There are a few reasons it is considered bad:

- Hard to debug (you've changed the language)
- Easy to break other code on the page that is not aware you've altered a prototype
- Possible clashes with future enhancements of the core.
- Probably lots more

Comment: Could you comment on a better alternative in your second example since you mentioned all the pitfalls involved.  I am trying to wrap my head around prototypes and am curious.

Answer (score 0):

I think, your first method adds only for this special property the alert() method. If you want create another instance, you have to do the same thing again. With protoype you define it more generally so you don't have to do the same thing again for another instance.

Perhaps http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/proto.shtml will help you to understand it better.